# Three.js gltf loader strange behavior when trying to add 3D text

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, gltf

The idea was to load the prebuilt gltf scene made in Blender. Then to add some 3D text using ttf loader and manipulate it.
I tried to use a code from examples and each loader works perfectly when I use them separately. But when I combine them into a single script really strange stuff starts happening. 
When I add a gltf scene first and after that, I add 3D text, the text magically disappears. Console says nothing. I tried to change the order of loading. When I load text after gltf, the content of gltf disappears and the only text stays visible. 
Screenshot:

[image: strange gltf loader behavior]

Console says

```
three.module.js:16177 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at WebGLIndexedBufferRenderer.setIndex (three.module.js:16177)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (three.module.js:23910)
    at renderObject (three.module.js:24601)
    at renderObjects (three.module.js:24571)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.module.js:24350)
    at render (main.js:73)
    at onAnimationFrame (<anonymous>:116:3)
    at <anonymous>:85:5
```

By excluding one-by-one item I figured out that this happens only when there's more than one 3D geometry object in gltf. When there's only one geometry object in gltf everything works fine.
I suggest there's something with the internal order of the objects, but have no idea how to fix this. 
Can someone explain to me what did I do wrong.

Here the code:

```js
import { GLTFLoader } from './jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import * as THREE from './libs/three.module.js';
import { TTFLoader } from './jsm/loaders/TTFLoader.js';

var container;
var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;
var mixer;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var group, textMesh1, textGeo, material;
var firstLetter = false;
var text = 'ttf',
    height = 0,
    size = 1,
    hover = 0,
    curveSegments = 4,
    bevelThickness = .1,
    bevelSize = 0;
var font = null;

container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1500 );
camera.position.set( 0, -10, 10 );
camera.zoom=1.5;
cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );
scene.add( camera );
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();



var loader = new GLTFLoader();
//loader.load( './text.gltf' , function ( gltf ) { //this one works fine
loader.load( './text+cube.gltf' , function ( gltf ) { //this one acts very strange
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
});


var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({'color': '#cece00'});
var loader2 = new TTFLoader();
loader2.load( 'fonts/ttf/kenpixel.ttf', function ( json ) {
    font = new THREE.Font( json );
    createText();
} );



var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 2 );
pointLight.position.set( 0, -50, 90 );
scene.add( pointLight );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true} );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false ); 
render();

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    if (mixer != null) {mixer.update(delta);};
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}



function createText() {
    textGeo = new THREE.TextBufferGeometry( text, {
        font: font,
        size: size,
        height: height,
        curveSegments: curveSegments,
        bevelThickness: bevelThickness,
        bevelSize: bevelSize,
        bevelEnabled: true
    } );

    textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
    textGeo.computeVertexNormals();
    var centerOffset = - 0.5 * ( textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x );
    textMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, material );
    textMesh1.position.x = centerOffset;
    textMesh1.position.y = hover;
    textMesh1.position.z = 0;
    textMesh1.rotation.x = 0;
    textMesh1.rotation.y = 0;
    scene.add( textMesh1 );
}
```

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>!!!TEST!!!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden}
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <script src="/libs/opentype.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[project files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PvcR5YR1Xa-t37JjE87ooljUqfzDefaE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please share `text+cube.gltf` and the relating files in this thread?

Comment: Thank you for the interest! Sure, already did, the link to the project files is at the bottom of the article. [And will add here, just in case:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PvcR5YR1Xa-t37JjE87ooljUqfzDefaE/view?usp=sharing). Full project in the single zip.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I imported from libs/three.module.js while GLTFLoader and TTFLoader both depend on the copy in build/three.module.js. Replaced

```js
import * as THREE from './libs/three.module.js';
```

with

```js
import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';
```

(thanks @donmccurdy from the official Three.js forum)